# transform a specific object format to a dataset format

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash, transform

I got such an object with a specific format like this:

```js
const o = {
  a: [1, 4],
  b: [2, 5],
  c: [3, 6],
  ...
}
```

Then i need to transform it to an dataset format like this:

```js
const data = [
  { a:"1", b:"2", c:"3" },
  { a:"4", b:"5". c:"6" },
  ...
]
```

I am wondering is there any built in functions in [lodash](https://lodash.com/) could implement this scenario or i could just easily do it by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Object.assign()`

```js
const o = {a: [1, 4], b: [2, 5], c: [3, 6]}

const r = []

for (let k in o)
  o[k].forEach((v, i) => 
    r[i] = Object.assign(r[i] || {}, {[k]: v}))

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`_.transform`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#transform).

```js
const
    object = { a: [1, 4], b: [2, 5], c: [3, 6] },
    result = _.transform(object, (r, a, k) => a.forEach((v, i) => {
        r[i] = r[i] || {};
        r[i][k] = v;
    }), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```